# Jquery - on click check if li item has display:none and then fade it in, else fade it Out

Tags: jquery, click, fadein, fadeout

Please advise. I'm using jQuery. I am begginer.  I wanted to show items with fadeIn (onclick), and then on second click to hide them with fadeOut. What's wrong with my code? Delays are important.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#btn").click(function(){ 
        if ($("sub-menu li").css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
                    });
        } else {
            $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeOut(500);
                     });
        }

    });
 });
```

Markup:

```
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>ONE</li>
        <li>TWO</li>
        <li>THREE</li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.sub-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aydo1evn/)

Comment: Please see my answer. You had only one single mistake that you missed dot from your class selector. I have fixed it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a better aprouch is by `fadeToggle` function which works like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#btn").click(function(){ 
       $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeToggle(500);
       });
    
 
 });
 });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.sub-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>ONE</li>
        <li>TWO</li>
        <li>THREE</li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    if ($(".sub-menu li").css('display') == 'none') //. was missing here
    {
      $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
      });
    } else {
      $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeOut(500);
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
    <li>FIVE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That was noobish :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#btn").click(function(){ 
   $(".sub-menu").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
 });
 });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>ONE</li>
        <li>TWO</li>
        <li>THREE</li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the [link](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) for fadetoggle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeToggle for this purpose.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){ 
     $('#navbar li').fadeToggle(1000); // Yourr calculation for toggle.
 });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.sub-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>ONE</li>
        <li>TWO</li>
        <li>THREE</li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#navbar li").toggle("slow")

  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
    <li>FIVE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use `.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. Actually you missed dot **.** from the following selector:

```
 $("sub-menu li");
```

Change the above to:

```
 $(".sub-menu li");
```

When selecting some elements using class, use dot to select that before class name. See the following fiddle..Its working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#btn").click(function(){ 
   if ($(".sub-menu li").css('display') == 'none') {
       $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
       });
    } else {
       $("#navbar li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeOut(500);
        });
    }
 });
 });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.sub-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>ONE</li>
        <li>TWO</li>
        <li>THREE</li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx much. This happens when you grow old :) Cheers!

Comment: @Razi - Please upvote and mark answer so that other can be benefitted :)